# Creating Data table using Key Value set in C#

Tags: c#, list, collections, datatable

I have dictionaries with key value as follows Dic1(Name,Anu), Dic2(Age,22),      Dic3(Name,Cas),Dic4(Age,25), Dic5(Sex,Male) . I want to create a data table with Name, Age and Sex as Column header and mapped with corresponding Values as the row data.

Name   Age   Sex
Anu    22    null
Cas    25    Male

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], with some sample data included (so we can use that as our starting point).

Comment: Do you know how to work with `DataTable`s in C#? Did you read the docs?

Comment: I am a beginner. I have knowledge in Python

Answer (score 1):

You should add `DataColumn` , `DataRow` separately, the below method convert a `List` collection to `DataTable` based on a [sample](https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-datatable) , Change the columns by your own problem.

```
static DataTable Convert(List<string[]> list)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    int columns = 0;
    foreach (var array in list)
    {
        if (array.Length > columns)
        {
            columns = array.Length;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add();
    }
    foreach (var array in list)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(array);
    }
    return table;
}
```

You can call that method by the following sample method:

```
static void sample()
{
    List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
    list.Add(new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" });
    list.Add(new string[] { "Row 2", "Row 2" });
    list.Add(new string[] { "Row 3" });

    DataTable table = Convert(list);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I modified this as per my requirement and it works